# As a beginner in pandas I do not quite understand what is the real deal with closed keyword in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What does it do when we specify `closed='left'`? I have read pandas documentation and it says closed is for the closed interval but i don't get it .

Comment: It is a mathematical term. See [Intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology)

Comment: It's inclusive vs exclusive. if the interval is `closed='left'`, then the left boundary is **included** and the right is **excluded** eg `[0, 10)` is `0 <= x < 10`

Comment: `closed = 'left'` means, `[x,y)` in math intervals.

Comment: If what you guys said is true then how can we do both ends closed as in [x,y] in terms of grouper?

Comment: I guess... `closed='both'` ([docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html))